# What's time complexity of this algorithm for getting all word ladders?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

> **Word Ladder**
>   Given two words (start and end), and a dictionary, 
>  find all
>   shortest transformation sequence(s) from start to end, 
>   **such that:**
>  Only one letter can be changed at a time Each intermediate word must exist in the dictionary
>
> **For example,**
>  Given: start = "**hit**"
>  end = "**cog**"
>  dict = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"] 
>  Return
>
> ```
> [ 
>   ["hit","hot","dot","dog","cog"], 
>   ["hit","hot","lot","log","cog"]
> ]
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>  All words have the same length.
>  All words contain only lowercase alphabetic characters.

---

> **Personally I think**, the time complexity for this algorithm depends on
>   the **input**(start, end, dict), can not write out like time complexity =
>   O(?).
>
> ---
>
> Thank you **AbcAeffchen**. The tight time complexity =
>   O(len*N*(26^(N/2))), len is the length of the given start string(or
>   end string), N is the number of elements of the dict.(Assume C++
>   unordered_set is implemented by has set). Pleas check details below.

**Idea of this solution: BFS(Map) + DFS.**[C++]

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string val;
    int level;
    vector<Node *> prevs;
    Node (string val, int level): val(val), level(level) {};
};

class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<string>> findLadders(string start, string end, unordered_set<string> &dict) {
    vector<vector<string>> list;

    // Input validation.
    if (start.compare(end) == 0) {
        vector<string> subList = {start, end};
        list.push_back(subList);
        return list;
    }

    deque<string> queue;
    unordered_map<string, Node *> map;

    queue.push_back(start);
    Node *start_node = new Node(start, 0);
    map.emplace(start, start_node);

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        // Dequeue.
        string curr_string = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();

        Node *curr_node = map.find(curr_string)->second;
        int curr_level = curr_node->level;

        int len = curr_string.length();

        if (curr_string.compare(end) == 0) {
            // Find the end.
            vector<string> subList;
            subList.push_back(curr_node->val);

            getAllPathes(curr_node, list, subList);

            return list;
        }

        // Iterate all children.
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
            char curr_original_char = curr_string[i];

            // Have a try.
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c ++) {
                if (c == curr_original_char) continue;
                curr_string[i] = c;

                if (dict.find(curr_string) != dict.end()) {
                    if (map.find(curr_string) == map.end()) {
                        // The new string has not been visited.
                        Node *child = new Node(curr_string, curr_level + 1);

                        // Add the parents of the current into prevs.
                        child->prevs.push_back(curr_node);

                        // Enqueue.
                        queue.push_back(curr_string);
                        map.emplace(curr_string, child);
                    } else {
                        // The new string has been visited.
                        Node *child = map.find(curr_string)->second;

                        if (child->level == curr_level + 1) {
                            child->prevs.push_back(curr_node);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Roll back.
            curr_string[i] = curr_original_char;
        }
    }

    return list;
}

void getAllPathes(Node *end, vector<vector<string>> &list, vector<string> &subList) {
    // Base case.
    if (end == NULL) {
        // Has been get to the top level, no topper one.
        vector<string> one_rest(subList);
        list.push_back(one_rest);
        return;
    }

    vector<Node *> prevs = end->prevs;

    if (prevs.size() > 0) {
        for (vector<Node *>::iterator it = prevs.begin();
             it != prevs.end(); it ++) {

            // Have a try.
            subList.insert(subList.begin(), (*it)->val);         

            // Do recursion.
            getAllPathes((*it), list, subList);

            // Roll back.
            subList.erase(subList.begin());
        }

    } else {
        // Do recursion.
        getAllPathes(NULL, list, subList);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Complexity is the time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the size of the input. Of course it depends on the size of the input, by definition. What exactly `O(?)` tells the reader that he doesn't already know?

Comment: Not time taken, but number of operations.

Comment: Agree with Jake Heidt----Not time taken, that is number of operations.

Comment: Algorithmic time is measured in operations. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Split-up

Lets split the complexity of in three parts:

1. Find a next word in transformation sequence
2. The length of a shortest transformation sequence
3. The number of transformation sequences

#### Assumptions

Let `n` be the length of the given words and `N` the number of words in the dictionary. Lets also assume that the dictionary is sorted.

#### 1. Part

Then you can find a next word in `O(n ⋅ 26 ⋅ log(N)) = O(n log N)` steps.

- `n` characters in your word, that can be changed.
- `26` possible changes per character.
- `log(N)` to look up, if this word exists in the dictionary.

#### 2. Part

How long can a shortest transforamtion sequence be?

*Example*: Let the start word be "aa", the end word "zz" and the dictionary
["ab", "bb", "bc", "cc", ..].
This example needs 26 transformations. I think you can build worst case inputs that needs something like 26<sup>n-1</sup> transformations.

But this depends on the words in the dictionary. So the worst case will be `N`, ie. all words in the dictionary are used.

#### 3. Part

How many different sequences exists?

Everytime you looking for the next word in the sequence, it is possible to find 26 different next steps. But only for the first half of the lenght of the shortest sequence, because this holds also if you switch start and end word. So there could be up to `O(26N/2)` different sequences, as long as the worst case lenght of a shortest sequence is `O(N)`.

#### Summary

- `O(n log N)` finding the next transformation in a sequence.
- `O(N)` transformations per sequence
- `O(26N/2)` different sequences.

In total you get `O(26N/2 N log N)`.

#### Notice

- This holds only if your dictionary can contain any sequence of characters as "words". If you only allow words, that exists in a real language, you can use statistics to proof a better complexity.
- The length of a shortest sequence is correlated to the number of different sequences. If you have a lot of words in your dictionary the sequence can become very long, but if you have too many, you maybe get more different sequences but they become also shorter. Maybe one can use some statistic to proof here also a better complexity.

I hope this helps

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you so much, AbcAeffchen. One more thing, I use C++ unordered_set for dict, which is implemented by hash set(not tree-set, not sequence), so personally I think, we need not assume the dict is sorted, and finding the next transformation in a sequence should be O(26 * n) = O(n).

Comment: You are right. If you can access the elements in O(1), you can find the next tranformation in `O(n)`. But I do not use c++ that much, so i cant say anything to the complexity of the function you use.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is very professional.